# Error: factory runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.7.1)

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, alchemy, sepolia

I have run into the above error trying to deploy my contract. Running npx hardhat scripts/deploy.js.
Here is the deploy.js:

```
async function main() {

    const Test1 = await ethers.getContractFactory("Test1");
  
  
    // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
  
    const test1 = await Test1.deploy()
  
    await test1.waitForDeployment()
  
    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", test1.address)
  
  }
  
  
  main()
  
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
  
    .catch((error) => {
  
      console.error(error)
  
      process.exit(1)
  
    })
```

Here is my hardhat.config:

```
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();


const { API_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
    defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
    networks: {
      sepolia: {
        url: `${API_KEY}`,
        account: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
        gas: 2100000,
        gasPrice: 8000000000,
        saveDeployments: true,
      }
    }
};
```

Also, I am 100% sure that my keys are working because this index.js script:

```
async function main() {
  const latestBlock = await ethers.provider.getBlock("latest");
  console.log("The latest block number is", latestBlock);
}

main();
```

returned this without issue:

```
The latest block number is Block {
  provider: HardhatEthersProvider {
    _hardhatProvider: LazyInitializationProviderAdapter {
      _providerFactory: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      _emitter: [EventEmitter],
      _initializingPromise: [Promise],
      provider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter]
    },
    _networkName: 'sepolia',
    _blockListeners: [],
    _transactionHashListeners: Map(0) {},
    _eventListeners: []
  },
  number: 4317743,
  hash: '0x958fcc2623779ccf65955ce0c9a6942610911428d604c0aad9a1409cad3f36d5',
  timestamp: 1695094548,
  parentHash: '0x6e92e3f483ac89882a72ae39c5691b8ebda83272fc2ea88841cd60abd49215bc',
  nonce: '0x0000000000000000',
  difficulty: 0n,
  gasLimit: 30000000n,
  gasUsed: 24226851n,
  miner: '0xF29Ff96aaEa6C9A1fBa851f74737f3c069d4f1a9',
  extraData: '0xd883010c00846765746888676f312e32302e34856c696e7578',
  baseFeePerGas: 21n
```

and I am seeing this reflected in my API.

I am seeing transactions on my API long after I try to run the deploy script but it doesn't seem to have actually done anything. THAT transaction method on my API is called eth_accounts and they are empty.

Comment: Kindly recheck your PRIVATE_KEY env 
or give a try to change `test1 = await Test1.deploy()` to `test1 = await ethers.deployContract('Test1')`.
Just guess

Comment: Unfortunately `test1 = await ethers.deployContract('Test1')` did not work. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardhat.config.js:

```
accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
```

plural 'accounts', not singular 'account'